# Browser "like" return button, with sessions

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

im trying to create a browser 'like' return button.

### To do so i created the **Code Below** to push the *Request::header('referer')* to my *Session::get('smartBacklinks')*

So far every Request::header('referer') that is different from the latest in the Session will be pushed to the session array. The next thing i need to do, and this is where im stuck. When i click on my return button, i will of course be redirected to the last url in my sessions array. The only thing wrong here is that i need to make sure that when the return button is clicked, it shouldnt run the code to push the Request::header('referer') into the session

```
    View::composer('backend.*', function($view)
    {   
        // If Session[smartBacklinks] is set.
        if(Session::has('smartBacklinks')){
            // Get the last item in Session array 
            $slice = array_slice(Session::get('smartBacklinks'), -1, 1);

            // Check if Request::header('referer') is equal to the $slide[0]
            if(Request::header('referer') != $slice[0]){
                // Check if Request::header('referer') is empty
                if(Request::header('referer') != '') Session::push('smartBacklinks', Request::header('referer'));
            }
        // If session[smartBacklinks] is not set. - Set
        }else {
            Session::put('smartBacklinks', [Request::header('referer')]);

            $slice = array_slice(Session::get('smartBacklinks'), -1, 1);
        }

        Session::save();

        $view->with('smartBacklinks', $slice[0]);
    });
```

Thanks in advance, i hope someone understands my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a form for the return button with some hidden value and check that value on each request. If a the return form is submitted you don't run the the referrer pushing code.

e.g.

```
if(empty($_POST['hidden_return'])){
// your push code
}else{
// the return button was clicked. Handle here
}
```

The html will be somthing like this

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_return" value="some_random_value" />
  <input type="submit" value="Click Here To Go Back!" />
  </form>
```